# Does OnsenUI support SwipeTableCell?

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I want to use from right to left swipe menu on OnsenUI it like IOS's mail app delete menu.
Does OnsenUI has function or similar fuction?
I guess realize it to be custom to ons-carousel.

Do you know easier solution or function?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the following [blog post](https://onsen.io/blog/developing-hybrid-mobile-apps-with-onsen-ui/), something similar has been implemented on the list elements.

Comment: Thank you for reply!
I try it!